# Looking for the right Table Widget

Tags: qt

I like to display a Table with 4 columns: the little dot, "Name", "Steps", "Time". See the appended picture.
When the user of this programm clicks on a line, the whole line should be selected and doubleclicking it should start the map.

Which Widget is the best for my purpose? Listview, Talbeview, ListWidget,...?
I am using Qt 5.6.0.

I tried to use QTableWidget, but it is more like an Excel-sheet.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can go with [QTableView](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtableview.html) as long as you do not need to work with item trees. You also need to implement your own data model based on [QAbstractTableModel](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qabstracttablemodel.html) class to display your data in QTableView widget. QTableView has `clicked()` and `doubleClicked()` signals which you can use to handle mouse clicks.